Should we close specific programming questions?
There are now and then questions like this one.
It's a clear and laser-like focused Q. All good. However, it's basically a die-hard computer programming question on a specific EEG toolbox in PsychoPy. Now, EEG is more than on-topic here, and today no scientist escapes this in siliconized arena of science. However, as I write in a comment on the linked question: 

I think a specific question like this is more suitable for the
  PsychoPi forum and your duplicate question there has four replies.
  Personally, I do not post any questions on the MATLAB PsychToolbox
  here either; as the respective forum is more suitable for these kinds
  of specifics. I went over to Bio Informatics SE and they regard your
  question as offtopic there, so migration is not an option. It will
  likely not be answered here either. Would you mind if this question is
  closed?

The reference to PTB-3 is quite apt - I would never ask a question on specific PTB-3 questions, as its respective forum is the prime place to go. Likewise, the PsychoPy forum has provided OP's Q over there with multiple answers.
Can we close specific scripting questions regarding toolboxes / programming environments with a custom close-reason as being too specific? 
With custom I mean that no standardized close reason is asked for, I'm just asking for feedback from the community. I left thw linked question open for now.

I would not close them. Those questions are on-topic. We are simply not a big enough community yet to ensure we have all the knowledge available here. Closing questions of people who might actually bring in that knowledge seems counterproductive.
Instead, I would (as you did) simply comment that there might be more suitable places to ask, and you could even encourage them to post an answer themselves once they have found it.

can I use he tag status-completed for this? Or is it off?

Not 100% certain. This is not so much a feature as it is a guideline. faq might be more appropriate.
